# IIS Hide GET Parameter From URL

Tags: php, regex, iis, url-rewriting

In server we are using Internet Information Services (IIS) with PHP, PHP Manager. I want to hide "dava" parameter, not only for /kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/ page, in whole website "dava" key should hide and should be page/value.

Current URL: http://localhost/kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme?dava=f2b80bf7

Expected URL: http://localhost/kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/f2b80bf7

My Currently Rules:

```
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Add .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/home" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="Rewrite to /home" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*[^\\]+)$" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/home/{R:1}.php" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
```

I Tried:

```
<rule name="Hide Query String" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="dava=(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
<rule name="Hide Query String" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^?]*)(\?.*)*$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="dava=(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article, the examples in the article will help you understand [how to create the correct rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

If you want to hide the "dava" parameter for /kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/ page, you can try the following rule:

> Current URL:
> http://localhost/kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme?dava=f2b80bf7
>
> Expected URL: http://localhost/kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/f2b80bf7

```
<rule name="Hide Query String">
    <match url="^kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/([0-9a-z]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme?dava={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If the "dava" key needs to be hidden in the entire website, you need to modify the rule according to the specific situation of your website,like:

```
<rule name="Hide Query String">
    <match url="(.*)/([0-9a-z]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?dava={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Also, when you have problems with IIS rewrite rules, you can try [using Failed Request Tracing to trace rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) for troubleshooting, and you can see how the rules are used internally.

Comment: Hi YurongDai, thanks for the answer but it didn't helped, i added your "entire website" code block to my current rules but when i follow this url "http://localhost/kovusturma-sartlari/onodeme/f2b80bf7" it returns 404 page error.

Comment: Have you tried [using Failed Request Tracing to trace rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) for troubleshooting?